# TypeError: int() argument must be a string,

Tags: python, arrays

This is my final for Intro to Programming Class

Write a program that does the following.

1 Create a function inputNumbers that uses a loop to allow the user to input 5 numbers between numbers between 1 and 10 and store them in an array called numArray.   Call the function from def main().(20 points)

2 Create a function addNums that accepts numArray and uses a loop to add the numbers in the array.    Call the function from def main(). Return the total to def main() and assign the total to a variable total.  Display total (20 points).

3 Create a function writeArray that writes contents of the array to a file called Exam2.dat, one number per line.  A new file should be created if a file called Exam2.dat currently exists.  Call the function from def main() (20 points)

4 Create a function readArray that reads contents of the file and adds them. Return the total to def main().  Call the function from def main() (25 points)

5 Display the total of the numbers in def main(). (5 points)

```
def main():
    numArray = inputNumbers()
    total = addNums(numArray)
    print(total)
    writeArray(numArray)
    readArray()

def inputNumbers():
    numArray = []
    numbers = [int(input('Enter a value between 1 and 10: ')) for i in range(5)]
    numArray.append(int(numbers))
    return numArray

def addNums(numArray):
    total = sum(numArray)
    return total

def writeArray(numArray):
    writeFile = open('Exam2.dat', 'w')
    for num in numArray:
        writeFile.write("%s\n" % numbers)

def readArray():
    result = 0
    for s in open('Exam2.dat'): result += int(s.strip())

main()
```

I am receiving the error

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

My question is : How do I write to an Array and then add it? I want the user to input 5 numbers (ex. 1,2,3,4,5) and it show me the total. hopefully the rest of the program is right

Comment: at line 11 is the error

Comment: You are `int`ing twice. Just remove the `int()` at line 11. `numbers` is already a list of `int`.

Comment: now it says:    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list' at line 15

Comment: Please read through the [Asking Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) section in Stackoverflow's help center. No hw questions, please.

Comment: @ReeseB. Get rid of the `append` also. Just concatenate with `+`. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `int()` at line 11. `numbers` is already a list of `int` (line 10). Change line 11 to this:

```
numArray += numbers
```

In fact, you could just return line 10. Change the function like this:

```
def inputNumbers():
    return [int(input('Enter a value between 1 and 10: ')) for i in range(5)]
```